# trying to iterating over dictionary but when the element is not found, else statement is not called, last key is printed instead

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, dictionary, iteration

I am trying to look for some food in the dictionary, if the food is not found I want to call the else statement but for some reasons when the food is not found the last key and its value in the dictionary gets printed instead. I need your help, please.

```
fridge = {"cheese" : "so delicious", "crackers": "you will love it once you try it", "chicken soup": "delicous stuff"}
food_sought = "pepper"
if food_sought:
    for food_sought in fridge:
        print("I was able to find a something in our list of food: %s : %s" % (food_sought, fridge[food_sought]))
        break
    else:
        print("We couldn't find the food you were looking for")
```

Comment: There's no last key or first key in simple dictionary.

Comment: I think I've fixed the indentation to match what you intended to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `if` instead of `for`:

```
fridge = {"cheese" : "so delicious", "crackers": "you will love it once you try it", "chicken soup": "delicous stuff"}
food_sought = "pepper"
if food_sought in fridge:
    print("I was able to find a something in our list of food: %s : %s" % (food_sought, fridge[food_sought]))
else:
    print("We couldn't find the food you were looking for")
```

---

If you really need to use `for .. in ..`, use different variable name. Or `food_sought` is overwritten.

```
fridge = {"cheese" : "so delicious", "crackers": "you will love it once you try it", "chicken soup": "delicous stuff"}
food_sought = "chicken"
for name in fridge:
    if name == food_sought:
        print("I was able to find a something in our list of food: %s : %s" % (food_sought, fridge[food_sought]))
        break
else:
    print("We couldn't find the food you were looking for")
```

Comment: I was trying to do an exercise and it asks to use for... in.

Comment: @user2824253, Is that excercise is about `for ... else ...` statement?

Comment: the exercise is from a chapter about if... elif...else, for...in

Comment: @user2824253, I added another code that use `for`. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `for ... in` then the way to go is this.

```
fridge = {"cheese" : "so delicious", "crackers": "you will love it once you try it", "chicken soup": "delicous stuff"}
food_sought = "pepper"

found = False
for food in fridge:
    if food == food_sought:
        found = True

if found:
    print('{} found'.format(food_sought))
else:
    print('{} not found'.format(food_sought))
```

Set the marker `found` to `False` before starting the loop. If you find the food somewhere in the loop set the marker to `True`. Check the condition after the loop.

You can optimize the code by leaving the loop with a `break` if the food was found.